# To update the cover in the face appears on the wall changed the picture, can I hide or delete this post with api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-page

to update the cover in the face appears on the wall changed the picture,
can i hide or delete this post with api ?.

```
      $json_object = $facebook->api($fanpage."/?  fields=cover&access_token=".$fanpage_token, 'get');
      echo $page_settings_url.'<pre>';
      print_r ($json_object);



      $json_object = $facebook->api($fanpage.'/'.$json_object['cover']['cover_id'],'delete');
      echo 'borrado'.$json_object;*/
      //echo $json_object['stdClass']['cover'];
      //$response = file_get_contents($page_settings_url);
      //$resp_obj = json_decode($response,true);
```

Comment: Hopefully you know some English, because the Google translation doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I *think* they're updating a Facebook Page's cover photo via the API and want to suppress the 'X added a new cover photo' story which gets added to the Page's Timeline automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my interpretation of your question is correct, you want to upload a page cover photo without a story appearing on the page's timeline?

This is covered in the [Page API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) - see the **Setting a Cover Photo** section

You can also add a `no_feed_story` parameter to the upload to suppress the news feed story.

So the code for uploading the cover photo would become:

`$json_object = $facebook->api($fanpage."/?  fields=cover&access_token=".$fanpage_token, 'POST', array('no_feed_story' => 1));`